# How to use IVI-C instruments-drivers (not IVI-COM)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, driver

I want to use IVI-C instruments-drivers (not IVI-COM) in Visual Studio 2012

Someone ever did this?

I only found examples for Visual Basic.

Drivers are downloadable on keysight.com-website which are free to use.

For VISA i installed Keysight IO-Libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar in Visual Studio 2013 using VB, but the basic principles will be similar for all languages. You probably know all of this already, but the question is a bit vague so here goes:

You need to install the drivers plus an SDK (which comes as a dll).  Hopefully the SDK will come with a manual of commands in your language of choice, but if not study the manufacturer's coding examples in VB or whatever.

It is easiest to use the languages provided in the SDK (usually VB and C#, maybe C++) otherwise you will have to write an interface between your language and the actual command syntax and work in a multi-language environment.

The drivers and the SDK need to be referenced in your project after you have installed them.  (MyProject, Reference Tab, use the Add command and Browse for the files.)  Sometimes its hard to find the correct files but VS 2013 is quite good at telling you when you get the wrong ones.

You may have to target your build (Build|Configuration Manager) on x86 processors because there are no x64 drivers for much of this kit - check with Keysight.

Then, in your code you will need to:

1. instantiate a copy of the driver for the specific instrument:
   `Dim MyDriver As New InstrumentManufacturersDriverName`
2. initialize it using the manufacturer's commands (on my kit initialization connects the driver to the physical interface via USB):
   MyDriver.Initialize(ParametersIfAny),
3. set up the ports you want to use (very dependent on the specific hardware)
4. program your commands.
5. Use a lot of patience and trial and error at first.

Best of luck - it's not so difficult.